# SonarQube ClassNotFoundException for python custom rule

Tags: python, sonarqube, classnotfoundexception

I have configured my SonarQube server and my python project in order to have all kind of analysis... (Quite normal...)

I'd like to add a rule to ensure I have put a license/copyright text at the beginning of all python script files. With the sslr-python-toolkit-1.5 app, I successfuly created the rule XPath and the rules is also created and activated on the SonarQube server.

BUT, when I launch a sonar analysis, I have a stacktrace :

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to initialize the XPath engine, perhaps because of an invalid query: //FILE_INPUT/STATEMENT[0][@tokenValue[not(contains(.,"''' Copyright .... '''"))]]
        at org.sonar.squidbridge.checks.AbstractXPathCheck.init(AbstractXPathCheck.java:47)
        at org.sonar.squidbridge.AstScanner.scanFiles(AstScanner.java:82)
        at org.sonar.plugins.python.PythonSquidSensor.execute(PythonSquidSensor.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jaxen.JaxenException: org.jaxen.saxpath.base.XPathReader
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
        at com.sonar.sslr.xpath.api.AstNodeXPathQuery.<init>(AstNodeXPathQuery.java:39)
        at com.sonar.sslr.xpath.api.AstNodeXPathQuery.create(AstNodeXPathQuery.java:103)
        at org.sonar.squidbridge.checks.AbstractXPathCheck.init(AbstractXPathCheck.java:45)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.jaxen.JaxenException: org.jaxen.saxpath.base.XPathReader
        at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.<init>(BaseXPath.java:125)
        at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.<init>(BaseXPath.java:142)
        at com.sonar.sslr.xpath.api.AstNodeXPathQuery.<init>(AstNodeXPathQuery.java:37)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: org.jaxen.saxpath.SAXPathException: org.jaxen.saxpath.base.XPathReader
        at org.jaxen.saxpath.helpers.XPathReaderFactory.createReader(XPathReaderFactory.java:152)
        at org.jaxen.saxpath.helpers.XPathReaderFactory.createReader(XPathReaderFactory.java:110)
        at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.<init>(BaseXPath.java:113)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.saxpath.base.XPathReader
        at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
        at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
        at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jaxen.saxpath.helpers.XPathReaderFactory.createReader(XPathReaderFactory.java:137)
        ... 39 more
```

1. I've tried to launch the sonar-scanner myself with the command line

   /usr/bin/java -cp sslr-python-toolkit-1.5.jar:sonar-scanner-cli-2.8.jar -Dscanner.home=/opt/sonar-scanner -Dproject.home=/home/dev/workspaces/pepyt org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main

but same result....

2. I've unzip both jars in a single directory and no change...
3. After some search I found some post about a sonar-java-libraries for the SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS environment variable... Event if the environment variable is used (seen in the sonar run log) that didn't solve the problem...
4. I put the sslr-python-toolkit-1.5.jar library in the lib directory of my sonar home directory without any success

I run out of idea...

How can I add the sslr python library to my sonar-scanner classpath in order to analyse the code with my custom rules?

Cormandyr

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-182) in the SonarQube Python plugin. It will be fixed in the next release. Thanks for your feedback!